# Is a pokemon's gender determined before it hatches from its egg?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

At what point is a pokemon's gender (or other stats) determined when it originates from an egg? Is it determined as soon as the egg is added to the player's inventory, or is it only determined when the egg hatches? (Or is it determined at some other time?)

I am particularly interested in the answer for Sun and Moon.

Comment: This would be a fairly significant change if the Pokemon gender is determined at the time of hatching. I've not found any reason to suspect the mechanic has changed from previous generations where the gender, along with other statistics, are generated when the egg is found.

Comment: @PhilD. There is a rather significant change this time around, in that egg statistics (stats/IVs/gender etc) are determined at some point before you pick up the egg from the Daycare, but I don't know when. I've saved, collected and hatched 5 pokemon, SR'd, then collected and hatched exactly the same pokemon, down to their IVs.

Comment: @MattTaylor That sounds like part of the behaviour I described, which is not new behaviour. In X&Y this behaviour was exploited in the [Time Machine Method](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2bNjUfd8AsITW1QUTBxTjB4bmc/edit).
The selection of IVs from parents etc was determined before the egg was found, allowing users to exploit this in the TM linked. I made a mistake in my earlier comment saying that it was _when_ the egg was found instead of sometime _before_. SO won't let me edit it.

Comment: No, the time machine methods works as I've described - once you pick up the previous egg from the daycare, the next one is randomised (which, when you're breeding the same pokemon, is equivalent to when you pick up the next one)

Comment: I would like to add as an update. That in SM the eggs are set long before you pick it up. if you save, hatch 30 eggs, soft reset and hatch 30 again. These eggs will have the same exact stats as the previous 30. In the corresponding order aswell.

This did however created a new way to farm Shinies a lot faster with the Masuda method. Link can be found [here](https://i.imgur.com/U2hgWit.png)

Answer (score 1):

Everything about Eggs is determined when you pick up the egg.

Additionally, nothing else (not even resetting) affects the Random Number Generator used for Eggs in Sun/Moon, which means unless you actually pick up (or decline) an Egg, soft resetting does nothing and you will pick up the exact same egg. In order to actually soft reset for Eggs, decline the Egg right after resetting, then save again so you can repeat the process until it corresponds to your wishes.

Since the RNG is deterministic when you know how it works (and there are programs that do), this allows precise control over your Eggs.

Comment: Have you tried it? The other answers says the exact opposite.

Comment: @Fabian I have. For the last 300 Eggs, I knew exactly what would come out of the egg thanks to the second part of my answer.